# Replace values in a dataset based off an index of values in another using base R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, dplyr, recode

```
structure(list(ID = c(123, 5345, 234, 453, 3656, 345), diagnosis_1 = c("B657", 
"B658", "B659", "B660", "B661", "B662"), diagnosis_2 = c("F8827", 
"G432", NA, "B657", NA, "H8940"), diagnosis_3 = c(NA, "B657", 
NA, NA, NA, "G432"), diagnosis_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "B657"
), diagnosis_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_6 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    diagnosis_8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_9 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), diagnosis_11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_12 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), age = c(54, 65, 23, 22, 33, 77)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to replace the values in the diagnosis columns with the values from this index:

```
B657    1
B658    2
B659    3
B660    4
B661    5
B662    1
F8827   3
G432    3
H8940   4
```

In reality the table has thousands of rows and I deal with other tables with a variable number of diagnosis columns so a solution which is agnostic to the number of columns would be ideal. The index is also up to a few hundred entries long..

If the index table was divided like this:

```
1 B657, B662
2 B658
3 B659, F8827, G432 
4 B660 H8940    
5 B661
```

Would that make a difference to the way it is coded?

The desired output would look like this:

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` to change content using a lookup table.

```
i <- startsWith(colnames(x), "diagnosis_")
x[,i] <- y[match(unlist(x[,i]), y[,1]),2]
x
#    ID diagnosis_1 diagnosis_2 diagnosis_3 diagnosis_4 diagnosis_5 diagnosis_6 diagnosis_7 diagnosis_8 diagnosis_9 diagnosis_10 diagnosis_11 diagnosis_12 diagnosis_13 age
#1  123           1           3          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  54
#2 5345           2           3           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  65
#3  234           3          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  23
#4  453           4           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  22
#5 3656           5          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  33
#6  345           1           4           3           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  77
```

And in case the lookup has a the given different structure:

```
zz <- strsplit(z, "[, ]+")
zz <- setNames(rep(seq_along(zz), lengths(zz)), unlist(zz))
i <- startsWith(colnames(x), "diagnosis_")
x[,i] <- zz[unlist(x[,i])]
```

In case codes are not found and you don't want to set them to NA.

```
i <- startsWith(colnames(x), "diagnosis_")
j <- match(unlist(x[,i]), y[,1])
k <- !is.na(j)
tt <- unlist(x[,i])
tt[k] <- y[j[k],2]
x[,i] <- tt
rm(i, j, k, tt)
```

Data:

```
x <- structure(list(ID = c(123, 5345, 234, 453, 3656, 345), diagnosis_1 = c("B657", 
"B658", "B659", "B660", "B661", "B662"), diagnosis_2 = c("F8827", 
"G432", NA, "B657", NA, "H8940"), diagnosis_3 = c(NA, "B657", 
NA, NA, NA, "G432"), diagnosis_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "B657"
), diagnosis_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_6 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    diagnosis_8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_9 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), diagnosis_11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_12 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), age = c(54, 65, 23, 22, 33, 77)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                         -6L), class = "data.frame")
y <- read.table(text="B657    1
B658    2
B659    3
B660    4
B661    5
B662    1
F8827   3
G432    3
H8940   4")
z <- readLines(con=textConnection("B657, B662
B658
B659, F8827, G432
B660 H8940
B661"))
```

Comment: Sorry I get this error: Error in '[.data.table'(x, , i): j (the 2nd argument inside {...}) is a single symbol but column name 'i' is not found. Perhpas you intended DT[, ..i]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

Comment: @tacrolimus I don't use `data.table`. Have you combined or modified the answer?

Comment: No I must have made the actual data a data.table at some point. Will revert it back and see what happens sorry!

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much

Comment: If you had a  little time would you object to talking through x[,i] <- y[match(unlist(x[,i]), y[,1]),2]? What does the 2 mean at the end?

Comment: The 2 at the end means, that it should take the second column from `y`. Which row it takes comes from `match`.

Comment: Thank you, finally, if the table has codes that don't appear in the index is there a way of ignoring them?

Comment: I have add *In case codes are not found and you don't want to set them to NA.*

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
df_replace <- read.table(text="B657    1
B658    2
B659    3
B660    4
B661    5
B662    1
F8827   3
G432    3
H8940   4", stringsAsFactors = F)

vec_repl <-  as.character(df_replace$V2)
names(vec_repl) <- df_replace$V1

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("diag")), ~str_replace_all(., vec_repl))
    ID diagnosis_1 diagnosis_2 diagnosis_3 diagnosis_4 diagnosis_5 diagnosis_6 diagnosis_7 diagnosis_8 diagnosis_9 diagnosis_10 diagnosis_11 diagnosis_12 diagnosis_13
1  123           1           3        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
2 5345           2           3           1        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
3  234           3        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
4  453           4           1        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
5 3656           5        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
6  345           1           4           3           1        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
  age
1  54
2  65
3  23
4  22
5  33
6  77
```

In base `R` you can try with the additional packe `stingr` this

```
df2 <- df
# use -c(1,ncol(df)) to select only columns where to replace values. 
df2[,-c(1,ncol(df))] <- lapply(df[,-c(1,ncol(df))], function(x) str_replace_all(x, vec_repl))
head(df2)
    ID diagnosis_1 diagnosis_2 diagnosis_3 diagnosis_4 diagnosis_5 diagnosis_6 diagnosis_7 diagnosis_8 diagnosis_9 diagnosis_10 diagnosis_11 diagnosis_12 diagnosis_13
1  123           1           3        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
2 5345           2           3           1        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
3  234           3        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
4  453           4           1        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
5 3656           5        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
6  345           1           4           3           1        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
  age
1  54
2  65
3  23
4  22
5  33
6  77
```

Comment: many thanks for taking the time to answer. This worked well

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to first construct a vector `tab_vec` with the old values as names and the new values and actual values. Afterwards, we can use the `recode` function from package `dplyr` (version `>= 1.0.0`) and use it `across` the variables whose name starts with the string `"diagnosis"`.

```
tab <- read.table(text="B657    1
B658    2
B659    3
B660    4
B661    5
B662    1
F8827   3
G432    3
H8940   4", header=F)

# create vector of replacements
tab_vec <- as.numeric(tab$V2)
names(tab_vec) <- tab$V1
tab_vec 

# substitute the replacement values in the dataframe df
dplyr::mutate(df, across(starts_with("diagnosis"), ~recode(as.character(.), !!!tab_vec)))
```

Output

```
    ID diagnosis_1 diagnosis_2 diagnosis_3 diagnosis_4 diagnosis_5 diagnosis_6 diagnosis_7 diagnosis_8 diagnosis_9 diagnosis_10 diagnosis_11 diagnosis_12 diagnosis_13 age
1  123           1           3          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  54
2 5345           2           3           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  65
3  234           3          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  23
4  453           4           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  22
5 3656           5          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  33
6  345           1           4           3           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  77
```

Comment: With your code I get `Error: no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "logical"`. That is because those columns with overall NA, e.g. `diagnosis_5`, belong to logical class. It's better to use `~ recode(as.character(.), !!!tab_vec)`.

Comment: Yeah I converted the types before but I did not insert it in my code. I will edit my answer with your suggestion which I prefer, thank you

Comment: Sorry I get the erorr: Evaluation error: could not find function 'across' . I have done library(dplyr) with no issues...

Comment: @tacrolimus `across` is the new function, as of dplyr version `1.0.0`, that has superseded all the scoped functions `*_at`, `*_if`, `*_all`. You probably need to update the `dplyr` package

Comment: ah!  I work on a HPC which is airlocked. Is there a way around without updating?

Comment: @tacrolimus Yes, if you have a dplyr version `< 1.0.0`, you can use the scoped variant `mutate_at` and the helper function `vars` as following: `dplyr::mutate_at(df, vars(starts_with("diagnosis")), ~recode(as.character(.), !!!tab_vec))`